# Count number of entries based on date

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time

I have the following sample data:

```
test={{{2020, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2020, 1, 2}, 1}, {{2020, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2020, 2, 1}, 2}, {{2020, 1, 1}, 3},{{2019, 1, 1}, 1}}
```

I would like to first group the data by month and year, and then count how many entries are in each group (1, 2, or 3).

I would like the output to look something like this to then create a separate dataset:

```
<|{{2020, 1},1} -> 2, {{2020, 1},2} -> 1, {{2020, 2},2} ->1,{{2020, 1},3} -> 1,{{2019, 1},1} -> 1|>
```

I have tried a couple of things based on other questions asked, but I have not managed to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any way of combining that so that the output would be something like this?: <|{{2020, 1},1} -> 2, {{2020, 1},2} -> 1, {{2020, 2},2} ->1,{{2020, 1},3} -> 1|>

Comment: Did you look at [`CountsBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountsBy.html)?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

test = {{{2020, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2020, 1, 2}, 1}, {{2020, 1, 1}, 
    2}, {{2020, 2, 1}, 2}, {{2020, 1, 1}, 3}, {{2019, 1, 1}, 1}};

assoc1 = CountsBy[test, {Most[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &]

(* <|{{2020, 1}, 1} -> 2, {{2020, 1}, 2} -> 1, {{2020, 2}, 2} -> 
  1, {{2020, 1}, 3} -> 1, {{2019, 1}, 1} -> 1|> *)

ds1 = Dataset@assoc1
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
assoc2 = CountsBy[test, {DateObject[#[[1]], "Month"], #[[2]]} &]
```

[image]

```
ds2 = Dataset@assoc2
```

[image]

Comment: As someone new to Mathematica, with the way the output is done, would it be possible to organize it into a timeseries?  Or would I need to get rid of the association?

Comment: Post a question showing an example of the intended input and the desired form of the output.